# Grab vtt subtitles from m3u8 stream

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles

I have a video stream http://content.uplynk.com/ext/6790c94a453741799d3f3fb3bc9023a4/2493079.m3u8 which can be perfectly grabbed by ffmpeg command

> ffmpeg -i "http://content.uplynk.com/ext/6790c94a453741799d3f3fb3bc9023a4/2493079.m3u8" -c copy CMA.ts

In this m3u8 list there is a subtitles stream http://content-aeui1.uplynk.com/395e08dcb0b54a3781d34d0b840df075/sub3.m3u8 , which has several vtt parts.

Is there a way to grab those vtt parts into single vtt file and then convert to some common format like srt ?

Or maybe there is a way to grab video with subtitles embedded?

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Comment: unfortunately no

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I know that the post is old, but here is a `ffmpeg` solution as you asked for.

```
ffmpeg -i 'https://example.com/link/to/subtitles_playlist.m3u8' subtitles.srt
```

Comment: I had the subtitle URI (in the master `.m3u8` file) as a single file name, so I got the error message "Can't support the subtitle". But the above command  with the original URL with the subtitle file name substituted worked.

Comment: This worked for me! I opened the master.m3u8 file, found the line beginning with `#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subtitles-0",NAME="English"` and used the following URI as the `ffmpeg` input.

Answer (score 3):

I would also suggest an ffmpeg solution, but with a different script:

```
ffmpeg -user_agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" -referer "about:blank" -i "https://example.com/link/to/subtitles_playlist.m3u8" -c copy "subtitle_eng.vtt"
```

Then convert the downloaded .vtt file to .srt (by Subtitle Edit for example)

Answer (score 1):

Try this program: [m3u8x](https://tajaribsoft-en.blogspot.com/2016/06/m3u8x.html#downloadx12)

m3u8x is to help you download and save m3u8-subtitle(.vtt), and convert to (.srt).

Copy the M3U8 file and then paste its file link to m3u8x... and click download

The product link also includes a tutorial.

[image: m3u8x image]

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be really working, I got a single .srt file finally !